# How to scrape next span tag?

Tags: html, python-3.x

Html code I want to scrape

```
<div class="breadcrumb_list breadcrumb_custom_cls" data-spm="breadcrumb" id="J_breadcrumb_list">
<ul class="breadcrumb" id="J_breadcrumb">
<li class="breadcrumb_item">
<span class="breadcrumb_item_text">
<a class="breadcrumb_item_anchor" href="https://www.lazada.vn/may-vi-tinh-laptop/" title="Computers &amp; Laptops">
<span>Computers &amp; Laptops</span>
<div class="breadcrumb_right_arrow"></div>
</a>
</span>
</li>
<li class="breadcrumb_item">
<span class="breadcrumb_item_text">
<a class="breadcrumb_item_anchor" href="https://www.lazada.vn/laptop/" title="Laptops">
<span>Laptops</span>
<div class="breadcrumb_right_arrow"></div>
</a>
</span>
</li>
<li class="breadcrumb_item">
<span class="breadcrumb_item_text">
<a class="breadcrumb_item_anchor" href="https://www.lazada.vn/laptop-co-ban/" title="Traditional Laptops">
<span>Traditional Laptops</span>
<div class="breadcrumb_right_arrow"></div>
</a>
</span>
</li>
```

My code to scrape first span tag (Computer & Laptop) using BeautifulSoup in Python 3. How can I access & scrape second span tag (Laptop)?

```
def get_url1(search_term1):
    template1 = 'https://www.lazada.vn//www.lazada.vn/products/{}.html'
    search_term1 = search_term1.replace(' ', '+')
    return template1.format(search_term1)

url1 = get_url1(tag1.get('href'))
driver.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results1 = soup1.find_all('div', {'id': 'J_breadcrumb_list'})
item1 = results1[0]
tag2 = item1.span.a
tag2.text.strip()
```

Comment: What you are looking for is not a class, but the content of a <span>, you simply need to search again on the results you got.

Comment: Oh tks, I will fix my code and my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many tks for all attentions. You can change the character in brackets 'item1 = results1[0]' to get the result.

My solution is

```
def get_url1(search_term1):
    template1 = 'https://www.lazada.vn//www.lazada.vn/products/{}.html'
    search_term1 = search_term1.replace(' ', '+')
    return template1.format(search_term1)

url1 = get_url1(tag1.get('href'))
driver.get(url1)

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results1 = soup1.find_all('span', class_='breadcrumb_item_text')

item1 = results1[0]
item1.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the content of a span tag. What you need to do is look for the `<span>` in the "soup" you have already obtained.

```
def get_url1(search_term1):
    template1 = 'https://www.lazada.vn//www.lazada.vn/products/{}.html'
    search_term1 = search_term1.replace(' ', '+')
    return template1.format(search_term1)

url1 = get_url1(tag1.get('href'))
driver.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

// New code
results1 = soup1.find_all('div', {'id': 'J_breadcrumb_list'})
results2 = results1.find_all('span')
```

`.find_all()` returns a list so you can iterate over the list and process the data. To get the content of the span tag, just access the attribute with `.text`.

```
def get_url1(search_term1):
    template1 = 'https://www.lazada.vn//www.lazada.vn/products/{}.html'
    search_term1 = search_term1.replace(' ', '+')
    return template1.format(search_term1)

url1 = get_url1(tag1.get('href'))
driver.get(url1)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

// New code
results1 = soup1.find_all('div', {'id': 'J_breadcrumb_list'})
results2 = results1.find_all('span')

for span in results2:
    print(span.text)
    // do staff
```

**Edit:** If I may, I would like to give you just a tip on the code, to make it clearer. Try to use meaningful names for the variables, so that it is much easier to read.

```
def getSearchUrl(keywords):
    keywords = search_term1.replace(' ', '+')
    url = f'https://www.lazada.vn//www.lazada.vn/products/{keywords}.html'
    return url

url = getSearchUrl(tag.get('href'))
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'J_breadcrumb_list'})
spans = divs.find_all('span')

for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
    // do staff
```

Comment: Many tks about your supported, I found solution to select second span tag

Comment: Tks for your solutionns, your solution 2 was perfected

Comment: @Mr.Bean If the answer is right, please mark it as 'right answer'